# Adding foreign key in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-first

I'm developing my first MVC project in Visual Studio 2012. Because i prefer "database first" approach i've started to design database.
The question is:
Why when i want to add foreign key i have all key properties disabled to edit (left):

[image]

I can only modify script directly (right) but is this really only solution?
Or i did something wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I also cannot edit foreign keys through the properties panel.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to to do is right click on the foreign key options on the right side of the table view and select add new foreign key. Then in T-SQL window you need to manually edit the the foreign key and foreign key table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to manually add the relationship? It'll allow you to change it however you like there.